# Node.js dom apis - jsdom, cheerio - can I use JS commands or do I need to use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

Is there any dom api for node.js in which I can use simply JS commands? I would like to avoid using jQuery cause I already get code in JS.

Comment: have you anything tried yet?

Comment: It looks like writing JS in jsdom is just fine - look at @b4rtekb answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can use JS code with jsdom module. By default it code example has:

```
var $ = window.$;
```

(to use jQuery) just change it to:

```
var document = window.document;
```

and you can use some JavaScript code like:

```
document.getElementById('yourid');
```

There is no jQuery to JavaScript converter cause jQuery is JavaScript. Everything you write in jQuery you can write in JavaScript - of course some of the code will be more complicated/bigger - thats why jQuery was invented (simpler code with good browser support).

Comment: It works! Dunno why official documentation use only jquery but it would be nice to show somewhere or just simply write that you can use JS too - like in you example.